# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized to upload my module kotlin to jcenter using bintray

Tags: maven, kotlin, bintray, jcenter

I´m going crazy....I´m trying to upload my kotlin module to JCenter using Bintray. I use a gradle script that I found in internet
this is my error

> Execution failed for task ':bintrayPublish'.
>   Could not publish 'drivesmart/DriveSmart_SDK/com.drivesmartsdk/0.0.1': HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [message:This resource requires authentication]

Gradle project

```
     classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
     classpath "com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1"
```

Gradle module

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
ext {
bintrayRepo = 'DriveSmart_SDK' // Repo name in bintray dashboard
bintrayName = 'com.drivesmartsdk' // package name of the bintray repo
userOrganisation = 'drivesmart'

publishedGroupId = 'com.drivesmartsdk'   // this is the ID we want to see in implementation line
libraryName = 'drivesmartsdk'     // this is the module name of library
artifact = 'drivesmartsdk'        // this is the artifact we want to see in implementation line

libraryDescription = 'SDK to collect data' // description of library

siteUrl = ''    // git repo url
gitUrl = '' // git repo vcs url

libraryVersion = '0.0.1'      // library version

developerId = 'andreslachica10'                // This is your bintray username
developerName = ''              // Developer's name
developerEmail = ''                // Developer's email

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'  // for example, The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'   // for example, http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]    // array of licenses, for example, ["Apache-2.0"]
```

}

My  organization 
[image]

Comment: How do you provide the api key?

Comment: Try using this: https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin